# Symfony cache permission with console

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, permissions

First, I have `APP_ENV=benchmark` in my .env.

After going to my site by a browser, `/var/cache/benchmark/` :

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech     98 janv. 16 12:31 annotations.map
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech   6198 janv. 16 12:31 annotations.php
drwxrwxrwx   2 www-data www-data  24576 janv. 16 12:27 Container3xlMUL6
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech      0 janv. 16 12:31 Container3xlMUL6.legacy
drwxrwxrwx   2 dometech dometech  24576 janv. 16 12:31 ContainerYBspTLo
drwxrwxrwx   3 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:31 doctrine
drwxrwxrwx  10 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:31 pools
drwxrwxrwx   9 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 16 12:31 profiler
drwxrwxrwx   2 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 16 12:31 sessions
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech 120497 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerCompiler.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech      6 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerDeprecations.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech    826 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.php
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech  36921 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.php.meta
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech  13649 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlGenerator.php
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech   2493 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlGenerator.php.meta
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech  10857 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlMatcher.php
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech   2493 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlMatcher.php.meta
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech 444567 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.xml
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech  36025 janv. 16 12:31 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.xml.meta
drwxrwxrwx   2 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 16 12:31 translations
drwxrwxrwx 140 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:31 twig
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dometech dometech   6846 janv. 16 12:31 validation.php
```

**Ok, no problem. After :**

- I run command `cache:clear`
- I run command `APP_ENV=benchmark ./bin/phpunit` (*= Fixtures and functionnals tests for benchmark (execution times, nb. query, etc.)*)
- I going to my site by a browser again, **I have this error** :

> Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/Bubblemeet/var/cache/benchmark/twig/c5).

This is my `/var/cache/benchmark/` now :

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dometech dometech     98 janv. 16 12:35 annotations.map
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  28672 janv. 16 12:35 Container3xlMUL6
drwxrwxrwx  2 dometech dometech  24576 janv. 16 12:34 ContainerYBspTLo
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data      0 janv. 16 12:35 ContainerYBspTLo.legacy
drwxrwxrwx  3 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 doctrine
drwxrwxrwx 10 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 pools
drwxr-xr-x  4 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 profiler
drwxr-xr-x  2 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 sessions
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dometech dometech 120497 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerCompiler.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 dometech dometech      6 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerDeprecations.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data    826 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.php
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data  36921 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.php.meta
-rw-r--r--  1 dometech dometech  13649 janv. 16 12:34 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlGenerator.php
-rw-r--r--  1 dometech dometech   2493 janv. 16 12:34 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlGenerator.php.meta
-rw-r--r--  1 dometech dometech  10857 janv. 16 12:34 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlMatcher.php
-rw-r--r--  1 dometech dometech   2493 janv. 16 12:34 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainerUrlMatcher.php.meta
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data 444270 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.xml
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data  36025 janv. 16 12:35 srcApp_KernelBenchmarkDebugContainer.xml.meta
drwxr-xr-x  2 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 translations
drwxr-xr-x 15 dometech dometech   4096 janv. 16 12:34 twig
```

**I think my app does not create the same permissions between my console and my browser but I do not know why.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver is running with the usual `www-data` user (which belongs to the `www-data` group), while your console call of PHPUnit created the cache with your shell user's user and group. This is common and should not be surprising - why should a shell user be able to write data using another user?

The most simple solution would be to use different environments, as you could also use different settings for running tests or accessing the rendered websites.

If you don't want to use different enviroments, [the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html) has some ideas for your:

- use the same user for shell and webserver (which means `www-data` should no longer be used)
- use ACLs for your cache folder (such that afterwards both the `www-data` user and your shell user have full permissions)